# R: require(foo, lib.loc=bar) does not forward lib.loc=bar to dependencies

Tags: r

I have a separate library folder. I installed `ks` as follows:

```
> install.packages('ks', lib='packages')

  There is a binary version available (and will be
  installed) but the source version is later:
   binary source
ks  1.9.2  1.9.4

also installing the dependencies 'KernSmooth', 'misc3d', 'mvtnorm', 'rgl', 'multi cool'
```

Now, I want to load these packages.

```
> require(ks, lib.loc='packages')
Loading required package: ks
Failed with error:  'package 'KernSmooth' required by 'ks' could not be found'
```

That is, `require` finds `ks` but not `KernSmooth` - because it is not trying to load `KernSmooth` from `packages`. I can load it manually:

```
> require(KernSmooth, lib.loc='packages')
Loading required package: KernSmooth
KernSmooth 2.23 loaded
Copyright M. P. Wand 1997-2009
Warning message:
package 'KernSmooth' was built under R version 3.1.2
```

I can try to `require(ks, lib.loc='packages)` again, but then it will tell me that the next package, `misc3d` is also not loaded yet.

Do I have to manually load all the dependencies from my library folder? I expected this to work automatically, i.e. if I `require(foo, bar)`, `foo` will also try to load its dependencies from `bar`.

Comment: Works as expected when trying different packages with dependencies, for example `np`. Issue perhaps specific to `ks`

Comment: We could use `available.packages()["ks","Depends"]`, a bit of regex, then install in a loop? I had the same issue, it is not specific to `ks`.

Answer (score 3):

The function `.libPaths` is used to get and set the paths where R looks for 
packages. If you do the following it should work just fine.

```
install.packages('ks', lib='packages')

.libPaths("packages")
require(ks)
```

In fact, if you plan on using `"packages"` a lot you can even set it before installing, which makes all your new packages go there by default.

```
.libPaths("packages")
.libPaths()
```

> ```
> [1] "/home/christofer/packages"     "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
> [3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
> ```

```
install.packages('ks')
```

> ```
> Installing package into ‘/home/christofer/packages’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> ...
> ```

```
require(ks)
```